# Use more than three colors in Material UI Primary Color Theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using `createMuiTheme()`, the `palette` object has gives you 3 options for you `primary` color, `light`, `main`, and `dark`. But what if you wanted a custom color like `medium_light` or `medium_dark` for `primary`? I ask this because I need 4 shades of a color for my UI, which is one more than you seem to be able to add to your `palette`. I know other fields allow you to store more colors, (`secondary`, `error`, etc.), but I'd like to have all four of these colors in `primary` in order to avoid confusion.

If this is not at all possible, what might be a sensible work-around?

```javascript
//theme.tsx
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core"; //4.11.4
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette:{
        primary: {
            light: "#8ab4c0",
            //medium_light?
            main: "#739eae",
            //medium_dark?
            dark: "#ddeaed",
        }
    },
    }
})
```

Comment: not possible is the answer. but u can create custom variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to create additional color in primary palette.

You may choose to use custom variable to store all your colors.
https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({   
    myColor: {
    fourth: orange[500],
    light: "#8ab4c0",
     main: "#739eae",
     dark: "#ddeaed",   }, });
```

Then u can use

```
`theme.myColor.fourth`
```

Comment: Don't you need to tell material UI you're using a custom variable? ```myColor``` does not exist on ```ThemeOptions``` so typescript throws an error

Comment: I don't use typescript so u need to refer to - https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/

Comment: Idk why you say it's not possible. Just create a const with the pallet key name and add whatever you want. 
`const primary = {
  main: '#BA3227',
  light: '#FF8C82',
  dark: '#A11C12',
  whatever: '#f7f7f7'
}`
Then you can do `theme.primary.whatever`. Typescript doesn't care either

Comment: Typescript cares and will fail to compile. https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33228 see the example I posted